# Correcting HTML sub folder links to main files

Tags: html, syntax, structure

I'm working on creating my first website and I've run into a problem. This is my file structure from my folder

```
 Info.html
 Blog.html
 Testimonials.html
 Contact.html
blog (folder)
---> blog-post.html (is inside blog folder)
```

The website has the same navigation on all of the main pages but the sub pages in the blog folder can only access other files within the blog folder. This makes it so that I cannot have `Mywebsite.com/blog/blog-post.html` link back to the info page as it's not in "blog" because it expects the link to come from the blog folder.

My question is, how can I keep the blog posts in a sub folder and still allow blog posts to contain links to the pages not within the blog folder?

Right now I'm structuring my navigation as such:

```
<nav><ul style="list-style-type:none">
     <li><a href="Info.html">Info</a></li>
</nav>
```

I want to avoid duplicate content but i'd also like to have the blog/blog-post in the URL.

Is there a syntax or attribute that I should be using to fix my issue or have I made a mistake within structuring the files of my website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this "/" to refer to the root folder

Like this

```
<nav><ul style="list-style-type:none">
     <li><a href="/Info.html">Info</a></li>
</nav>
```